# How will you implement pow(a,b) in C ? condition follows --

Tags: c

without using multiplication or division operators. 
You can use only add/substract operators.

Comment: What, no comparison operators?

Comment: What about the assignment operator?  Can that operator be used?

Comment: "How will you implement pow(a,b) in C without using multiplication or division operators"? I wouldn't.

Comment: Is this homework by any chance?

Comment: And what about loops? Or do we have to loop with recursion?

Comment: Sorry guys, I think that even semicolons are banned.

Comment: @Matteo, okay, so that leaves macros. `#` isn't technically an operator, is it?

Comment: @bdonal: `pow` implemented with just string concatenation seems a fun exercise to do. `:D`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pointless problem, but solvable with the properties of logarithms:

```
pow(a,b) = exp( b * log(a) )
         = exp( exp(log(b) + log(log(a)) )
```

Take care to insure that your exponential and logarithm functions are using the same base.

---

Yes, I know how to use a sliderule. Learning that trick will change your perspective of logarithms.

Comment: Isn't that `exp(b * log(a))`? Considering that `pow(a, b)` usually means "a raised to the power of b", not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

If they are integers, it's simple to turn pow (a, b) into b multiplications of a.

```
pow(a, b) = a * a * a * a ... ; // do this b times
```

And simple to turn a * a into additions

```
a * a = a + a + a + a + ... ; // do this a times
```

If you combine them, you can make pow.

First, make mult(int a, int b), then use it to make pow.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive solution :

```
#include<stdio.h>




    int multiplication(int a1, int b1)
    {
       if(b1)
         return (a1 + multiplication(a1, b1-1));
       else
         return 0;
    }

   int pow(int a, int b)
    {

       if(b)
         return multiplication(a, pow(a, b-1));
       else
         return 1;
    }    


    int main()
    {
      printf("\n %d", pow(5, 4));
    }
```

Comment: This would fail miserably for large exponents :)

Answer (score 0):

You've already gotten answers purely for FP and purely for integers. Here's one for a FP number raised to an integer power:

```
double power(double x, int y) { 
    double z = 1.0;

    while (y > 0) {
        while (!(y&1)) {
            y >>= 2;
            x *= x;
        }
        --y;
        z = x * z;
    }
    return z;
}
```

At the moment this uses multiplication. You can implement multiplication using only bit shifts, a few bit comparisons, and addition. For integers it looks like this:

```
int mul(int x, int y) { 
    int result = 0;
    while (y) { 
        if (y&1)
            result += x;
        x <<= 1;
        y >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Floating point is pretty much the same, except you have to normalize your results -- i.e., in essence, a floating point number is 1) a significand expressed as a (usually fairly large) integer, and 2) a scale factor. If you want to produce normal IEEE floating point numbers a few parts get a bit ugly though -- for example, the scale factor is stored as a "bias" number instead of any of the usual 1's complement, 2's complement, etc., so working with it is clumsy (basically, each operation you subtract off the bias, do the operation, check for overflow, and (assuming it hasn't overflowed) add the bias back on again).

Doing the job without any kind of logical tests sounds (to me) like it probably wasn't really intended. For quite a few computer architecture classes, it's interesting to reduce a problem to primitive operations you can express directly in hardware (e.g., bit shifts, bitwise-`AND`, -`OR` and -`NOT`, etc.) The implementation shown above fits that reasonably well (if you want to get technical, an adder takes a few gates, but VHDL, Verilog, etc., but it's included in things like VHDL and Verilog anyway).